# It keeps telling me the name doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code it's in C#? newOrder is underlined in red and the error says Error The name 'newOrder' does not exist in the current context

```
public partial class BagOrder : Form
{
    public BagOrder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bagOrder_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        newOrder = new Order();
        for (int i = 0; i < newOrder.menuBag.Length; i++)
        {
            this.lstBxBagType.Items.Add
                (newOrder.menuBag[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you never declared newOrder...try `var newOrder = new Order();`

Comment: Where do you declare newOrder ? is it a class member ? Or is it just a local variable in method bagOrder_Load ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f.aspx) is the detailed explanation of your error:

**Compiler Error CS0103**

> The name 'identifier' does not exist in the current context
>
> An attempt was made to use a name that does not exist in the class,
>   namespace, or scope. Check the spelling of the name and check your
>   using directives and assembly references to make sure that the name
>   that you are trying to use is available.
>
> This error frequently occurs if you declare a variable in a loop or a
>   try or if block and then attempt to access it from an enclosing code
>   block or a separate code block, as shown in the following example.

And here is an example of a [declaration statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx)

```
// Declaration statement. 
int counter;
```

You need to define `newOrder` variable and you need to specify the type or use `var` keyword to *implicit type definition*.

If you want to access your variable from anywhere inside of your class define it in the top of your class:

```
public partial class BagOrder : Form
{
   Order newOrder;
   ...
}
```

Don't forget to initialize it like this:

```
newOrder = new Order();
```

Then you can access it from everywhere inside of your class.

**Further Reading**

- [3.7 Scopes - C#Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [What's The Difference, Part Two: Scope vs Declaration Space vs
  Lifetime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/03/what-s-the-difference-part-two-scope-vs-declaration-space-vs-lifetime.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void bagOrder_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            Order newOrder = new Order();
            for (int i = 0; i < newOrder.menuBag.Length; i++)
            {
                this.lstBxBagType.Items.Add
                    (newOrder.menuBag[i]);
            }


         }
```

Try the above

Comment: Looks like newOrder is undefined, so you need to add Order newOrder = new Order();

Comment: I did this and it worked for the first couple of ones but the rest on the bottom are still underlined.